# scrolling child div in absolute positioned parent

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I have layout like this:

Entire right content's `position` is `absolute`

I want to be able scroll only this `I should scroll` boxes and this gray content to stay in his place.

Code and playground on => [codepen](https://s.codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/WGvYqZ)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify your CSS file

```
.user-search-box .result-list{
  position: absolute;
  max-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```